# Location of formatter files for VIM

Tags: formatting, vim

I found the following code snippet on the internet, and want to use it in my own `.vimrc`.

```
augroup CodeFormatters
    autocmd!

    autocmd  BufReadPost,FileReadPost   *.py    :silent %!PythonTidy.py
augroup END
```

However, I'm not quite sure where to put the `PythonTidy.py` script, so that it is accessible from everywhere.
Furthermore I read that using `BufReadPre` is better than `BufReadPost`, respectively `FileReadPre`, is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, `PythonTidy.py` must be accessible through your `PATH`. If you have a convenient place already contained in there, e.g. `~/bin`, just place it there.

Alternatively, you can place it somewhere into your `.vim` directory, and use something like `expand('<sfile>:p:h')` to resolve the directory of your Vimscript, and build a relative path from there.

As you want to filter the read buffer contents with the `:%!` command, you have to use the `BufReadPost` event; with `BufReadPre`, the buffer hasn't yet been read and nothing would be sent to the filter.

Answer (score 0):

`PythonTidy` is a command line executable: put it somewhere in your `$PATH`.

You can also put it anywhere and use an absolute path in the `autocmd`:

```
autocmd  BufReadPost,FileReadPost *.py :silent %!/path/to/PythonTidy.py
```